# Error en los metodos dentro de una clase

Tags: java, class

Debo realizar una clase con las cuatro operaciones básicas, me aparece un error en los métodos pero no entiendo a que se debe, el siguiente error `source_file.java:11: error: missing return statement }// cierre constructor`, también aparece para la fila 33 pero no veo como arreglarlo, gracias.

```java
class Operaciones {
    protected int numero1;
    protected int numero2;

    public int Suma() {
        numero1 = 0;
        numero2 = 0;
    }// cierre constructor

    public void setNumero1 (int numero1) {
        this.numero1 = numero1;
    }//cierre escritura numero 1

    public int getNumero1 () {
        return this.numero1;
    }// cierre lectura numero1

    public void setNumero2 (int numero2) {
        this.numero2 = numero2;
    }//cierre escritura numero 1

    public int getNumero2 () {
        return this.numero2;
    }// cierre lectura numero2

    public int sumar () {
        return getNumero1() + getNumero2 ();
    }//cierre de suma

    public int Resta() {
        numero1 = 0;
        numero2 = 0;
    }// cierre constructor 

    public void setNumero3 (int numero1) {
        this.numero1 = numero1;
    }//cierre escritura numero 1

    public int getNumero3 () {
        return this.numero1;
    }// cierre lectura numero1

    public void setNumero4 (int numero2) {
        this.numero2 = numero2;
    }//cierre escritura numero 1

    public int getNumero4 () {
        return this.numero2;
    }// cierre lectura numero2

    public int restar () {
        return getNumero3() - getNumero4 ();
    }//cierre de resta

}//cierre clase operacion
```

Answer (score 2):

Eso te aparece porque debes si o si retornar un entero (definiste como valor de retorno un `int`) en el metodo, pero ten en cuenta que tu estas definiendo dos enteros:

```
public int Suma() {
    numero1 = 0;
    numero2 = 0;
}
```

**Solo puedes retornar uno de ellos** y supongo querras retornar la suma entre ambos, asi que puedes cambiar ese metodo a:

```
public int Suma() {
    numero1 = 0;
    numero2 = 0;
    return numero1 + numero2;
}
```

De hecho eso mismo te esta pasando en la resta, donde **debes retornar algo** y no estas retornando nada:

```
public int Resta() {
    numero1 = 0;
    numero2 = 0;
}
```

deberias tener:

```
public int Resta() {
    numero1 = 0;
    numero2 = 0;
    return numero1 - numero 2;
}
```

Que por cierto no se porque los reseteas... pero bueno.

Por cierto no tienes constructor, pero realmente no es necesario colocarlo.

Si quieres un constructor tu constructor debera llamarse igual que tu clase, de esta manera:

```
class Operaciones {

   //Este si es el constructor de tu clase
   Operaciones(){

   }

   //Esto no es un constructor, es un metodo de la clase
   public int Suma() {
      numero1 = 0;
      numero2 = 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Int Suma()
public Int Resta()
```

Esas líneas de código no son constructores un constructor se caracteriza por tener el mismo nombre de la clase y no tiene un tipo de dato asociado. En este caso tu constructor debería llamarse:

```
public Operaciones()
```

Sin tipo de dato.

Por  este motivo los métodos Suma y Resta al no ser constructores, son métodos que deben retornar un número entero y por eso no te compila la clase ya que no tienen la cláusula return.

Answer (score 0):

El constructor se crea con el mismo nombre de la clase

```
public Operaciones() {

}//Constructor vacío

public Operaciones(int a, int b) {
     this.numero1 = a;
     this.numero2 = b;
}
```